# justify-content-between will not work for two items in a div container

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

Trying to put two elements on opposite ends of a div container using justify-content-between per the Boostrap doc [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/). However, it will not put the items on opposite ends of the row. How can I put the h4 element to the left and the button to the right? I'm using BS 5.2.3. Thank you. [Here](https://codepen.io/centem/pen/mdzjNXZ?editors=1010) is a codepen of the same code.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row" id="paytable-heading">
    <div class="col justify-content-between">
      <h4>Pay Tables</h4>
      <!-- Button trigger modal -->
      <button
        type="button"
        class="btn btn-primary"
        data-bs-toggle="modal"
        data-bs-target="#exampleModal"
        id="modalButton"
      >
        Enter New Pay Rates
      </button>
      <hr>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
<div class="col justify-content-between">
```

to

```
<div class="col d-flex justify-content-between">
```

You need to set the display of the div to flex since `justify-content-between` won't work on `display: block`

```html
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.0.2/css/bootstrap.min.css'>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row" id="paytable-heading">
    <div class="col d-flex justify-content-between">
      <h4>Pay Tables</h4>
      <!-- Button trigger modal -->
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal" id="modalButton">
            Enter New Pay Rates
          </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.2.3/js/bootstrap.min.js'></script>
```